# If I edit my answer, does the asker get a notification?

Tags: support

... if they don't, what's the right "protocol" to "let them know" that I've significantly improved the answer?

Comment: If you really significantly changed your answer, and there was no other answer already having that content, you might ping him (on your own post or on the question). Though only do that sparingly, and mention the main changes concisely.

Comment: From time to time I find myself coming back to my answer and thinking "goodness, I can add a paragraph to explain more or better".   This is not a 
"significant change" in the sense of "rectified an error", but rather "this extra information likely will help".   Based on the answer below, I now understand that I can comment on my answer to make the asker aware, and I can see that this should be done sparingly: not for fixing typoes, but for adding significant useful information.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, edits to existing answers to a question do not trigger a notification to the person who wrote the question; they're notified of *new* answers, edits to their *question* (or to an answer they wrote, if it was self-answered) and new comments to either the question, or its answers.

There is, however, a feature request to have the OP notified of answer-edits: [Could we have a way to notify users when an answer is edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157248/could-we-have-a-way-to-notify-users-when-an-answer-is-edited)

Current practice seems to be to add a comment, along the lines of: "I updated my answer based on (new information, new requests, clarifications)."

I, personally, try to explain the updates (and the rationale for the updates/edits) in the answer itself as I edit it, others find it more appropriate to explain that in the same comment notifying the OP of the edits. I'm not sure either approach is necessarily best, so long as the edits are explained somewhere.

Comment: Anyone having favorited the question can look at his favorites to determine which of them had any changes (Q+A+Comments).

Comment: True, but...was that a criticism of my answer (or an omission therein), or a workaround for the lack of notifications?

Comment: A workaround even useful for others than the asker. And thus an addition.

Comment: Having read this answer, I now know what I needed to know (thanks).  In addition, I think I lean in the direction of "the status quo is good" ... if you need to notify the asker that you edited, you can (by making a comment) ... but if you were just fixing a typo you don't end up spamming them with a notification.  I like that.

Comment: Are question authors really/still notified about comments under other people's *answers*? And that comment you mention as common practice, do you mean under the answer or under the question? (Btw, in either case, such a comment risks getting deleted, particularly under the question, where it's rather inappropriate.)